# Initialising an abstract class in c++ with pure virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I'm trying to resolve this - I have a base class:

```
class Original {
private:
    string inputPath;
    string outputPath;
public:
    void takeInput(string path);
    void putOutput(string input, string output);
    virtual void doFilter(ifstream &in, ofstream &out) = 0;
    virtual char transform(char a) = 0;   
};
```

And a class which implements it:

```
class Transform : public Original {
public:
    char transform(char a);
};
```

But when I try to use the `Transform` class in main, like

```
Transform t;
Original *org = *t;
```

it gives me an error

```
Variable type 'Transform' is an abstract class.
```

I've implemented some stuff in Transform::transform, and now totally lost.
How do I initialize Transform class?

Comment: You also wan to write `Original *org = &t;`

Answer (score 3):

There are *two* pure virtual member functions in `Original`:

```
class Original {
    // ...
    virtual void doFilter(ifstream &in, ofstream &out) = 0;
    virtual char transform(char a) = 0;   
};
```

You provided an override for `transform` in `Transform`, but `doFilter` is still pure virtual. Since `Transform` has a pure virtual member function, it too is considered an abstract class that cannot be constructed. In order to construct a `Transform`, you will need to provide an override for the second function too.

Comment: He didn't define an override.

Comment: @DonLarynx OP didn't provide *any* definitions - it's a safe assumption that they exist given that the question is about a compile error and not a linker error.

Comment: @DonLarynx: He didn't show definitions; if those don't exist either then that's a separate problem he'll have to sort out once he's got compilation working. The fact that he didn't _declare_ an override for `doFilter` is the more pertinent point in this question.